# How to store Strings that can be queried in Room?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I want to store Strings (uids) in my Room DB. I want these uids to be able to be:

- Queried (check to see if a uid exists in my list of strings)
- Added to (add a uid to the list of strings)

What is the most efficient way to achieve this?

Here is my skeleton to give you some context, though my understanding of Room is very basic so there will be mistakes:

```
@Entity(tableName = "user_data")
data class UserData(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val uid: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "matched_users") var matchedUsers: Set<String>
)


@Dao
interface UserDataDao {
    // Check to see if the uid is in matchedUsers Set/List
    @Query("SELECT * FROM user_data WHERE :matchId IN matched_users")
    fun matchedBefore(matchId: String): Boolean

    // Add uid to Set/List
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.ABORT)
    fun addMatchUid(uid: String)
}
```

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

According to your context, it seems you want to build `one-to-many` relationship, to do so you can follow the bellow codes. If not let me know what exactly you want.

```
@Entity(tableName = "user_data")
data class UserData(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val uid: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "name") var name: String
)

@Entity(tableName = "user_matcher")
data class UserMatcher(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val uid: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "userId") var userId: Int
)


@Dao
interface UserMatcherDao {
    // Check to see if the uid is in matchedUsers Set/List
    @Query("SELECT m.id as mid, u.id as uid, u.name FROM user_matcher m INNER JOIN user_data u ON m.userId = u.id WHERE m.id = :matchId")
    fun getMatchedUsers(matchId: Int): List<UserData>
}
```